# zclip: refer to sender element in afterCopy callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

I have multipule "copy code" buttons on one page. Each code has its own button.

here is my basic html:

```
<a id="1" href="#" class="small-white-btn copyme">Copy Source</a>    
<div id="code-1" style="display:none;">html source code goes here</div>
<div class="msg1"></div>

<a id="2" href="#" class="small-white-btn copyme">Copy Source</a>   
<div id="code-2" style="display:none;">html source code goes here</div>
<div class="msg2"></div>
```

My zclip jquery looks like this:

```
$('.copyme').zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var copythis = $('#code-' + id).text();
        return copythis;
    },
    afterCopy: function () {
        $("div.msg" + id).html("<p>Source Code Copied</p>");
    }
});
```

This works, however, I cannot get the message injected into the div `class="msg"` tag.

How can I target the var id, add it to the div msg and display it on the page when the button is clicked.

Comment: Did you try using var id = $(this).attr('id'); (same as in copy function)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you cannot access the `id` variable you created in the `copy` function from `afterCopy` is because variables defined inside of a function are [scoped to that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). However, this is easily overcomable.

There is no need to save the value from `$(this).attr('id')` as a global variable when the `copy` function is called, because you can just as easily get the id of the calling element in the `afterCopy` function by using *the same exact expression*:  i.e.

```js
afterCopy: function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

This answers your original question, but there is a much better way to determine which elements to select.  Rather than relying on the `ID` field to never change and using it to construct the id of another element, you can just store the exact id of your copy text and copy message elements in the form of [**custom data-* attributes**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) on your `.copyme` `anchor`, like this:

```html
<a data-copy="#code-1" data-copy-msg="#msg1" class="copyme">Copy Source 1</a>
```

Then, in the `copy` function, you can grab that attribute and pass it into a jQuery selector to get the text value to copy, like this:

```js
copy: function () {
    var copySelector = $(this).data('copy');
    return $(copySelector).text();
}
```

You can handle the `afterCopy` event the same way.  You can use `this` instead of having to store the ID in memory.  Grab the selector where you want the message to go, and apply the html to that, like this:

```js
afterCopy: function () {
    var copyMsgSelector = $(this).data('copy-msg');
    $(copyMsgSelector).html("Source Code Copied");
}
```

---

## [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/34bN3/)

---

So the whole thing would look like this:

**HTML**:

```html
<a data-copy="#code-1" data-copy-msg="#msg1"
   href="#" class="copyme" >Copy Source 1</a> 
<div id="code-1" style="display:none;">source code 1</div>
<span id="msg1"></span>

<br/>
<a data-copy="#code-2" data-copy-msg="#msg2"
   href="#" class="copyme" >Copy Source 2</a> 
<div id="code-2" style="display:none;">source code 2</div>
<span id="msg2"></span>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$('.copyme').zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
        var copySelector = $(this).data('copy');
        return $(copySelector).text();
    },
    afterCopy: function () {
        var copyMsgSelector = $(this).data('copy-msg');
        $(copyMsgSelector).html("Source Code Copied");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1: great and very verbose! (Although storing copy msg selectors seems to be a little overkill for this but particular need)

Comment: Thanks, although verbose means [using more words than are needed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbose), and I'm not sure that's what you meant.  Secondly, I don't think storing selectors is overkill at all.  Overkill how?  You're not going to take any performance hit.  You want your markup to be as semantically clear as possible.  Since our `a` tag is directly communicating with another `div` and `span`, the best case scenario would be for our anchor itself to specify which ones.  Constructing id tags handcuffs you into your naming choices and is subject to breaking easily.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring var id within a function, so it's a private variable that gets destroyed after the function finishes running. You need to declare the variable outside of your function; then when it runs you can assign and preserve the value.

try this:

```
var id;
$('.copyme').zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function () {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        var copythis = $('#code-' + id).text();
        return copythis;
    },
    afterCopy: function () {

        $("div.msg" + id).html("<p>Source Code Copied</p>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Using a global variable (var id;) will make your code quite messy: what if your fellow programmer also defines global var id for similar needs? You'll get a race condition where different parts of the system would override its value randomly - so your CopyFinished would read a value, set by somebody else. Please, either use afterCopy: function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
} or data attributes form @KyleMit 's answer

Comment: +1 as this isn't a *bad* answer.  There's no need to downvote anything here.  If another developer comes along and absolutely needs `id` then you can rename this to something specific like `copiedItemId`.  That shouldn't pose any conflicts.  Since we can do without it, I think that's better, but this does minimally answer OP's question.